# Eclipse adt 23.02 does not work properly on program start

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows, adt

There's hard to name this problem so that i attach screen. It starts normally. All preferences seems to be ok. It has been restarted several times and it does not work. Can not open any perspective. Every option from main menu is disabled(grey text).

Regards

[image]